# dependent dropdown list using jsp

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, drop-down-menu

Good day, guys. I have two dropdown lists in my jsp. Both of them are populated by connecting to a database (MySQL). The first dropdown is a dropdown for companies while the second is for the suppliers per company. Now, I want the second dropdown to be dependent from the first dropdown list which means that the list of suppliers that will be presented in the second dropdown will depend to the selected company from the first dropdown. Is there any way that I can get the selected value from the first dropdown then just add it to the `WHERE CLAUSE` query of the second dropdown? or can you give any suggestions on how I can achieve this? If possible, can I achieve this without using any javascript, jquery or ajax? Thank you in advanced! Here is my code below:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<sql:setDataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
                   url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/chkdb"
                   user = "root"
                   password = ""/>
<sql:query var="companies">
    SELECT compCode, cname FROM companies
</sql:query>
<sql:query var="suppliers">
    SELECT compCode, name FROM suppliers 
</sql:query>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP 1</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="deliveries" method="POST" id="deliveriesForm">
            <p class="label">Company:</p>
                            <select name="companyList"> 
                                    <c:forEach var="compName" items="${companies.rows}">
                                        <option value ="${compName.compCode}">${compName.cname}</option>
                                    </c:forEach> 
                             </select></br>
            <p class="label">Supplier: </p>
                             <select name="supplierList"> 
                                    <c:forEach var="suppName" items="${suppliers.rows}">
                                        <option value ="${suppName.compCode}" >${suppName.name}</option>
                                    </c:forEach> 
                             </select></br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First suggestion: Don't do queries in JSP. Use a controller (i.e. servlet). Second suggestion: Don't be afraid of jQuery or Ajax. You can do it without them, but it will be a mess without them.

Comment: @developerwjk I'll use a servlet after this part. that servlet will insert the values to the database from this jsp. I'm focusing on jsps first before going to jquery and ajax. Still, thank you for the suggestions! Any other suggestions I can do to resolve my code?

Comment: Take a look at the info page for the servlets tag to see what I'm getting at: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info